# Worklight 7.1 Jsonstore with sqlcipher giving PERSISTENT_STORE_FAILURE in windows 8.1 javascript hybrid project

Tags: runtime-error, ibm-mobilefirst, sqlcipher, jsonstore

I am working in IBM worklight hybrid application. This issue is happening on my Windows environment.

Following [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_replacing_SQLite_with_SQLCipher_W81.html) I replaced the sqlite3.dll in the project, But always getting PERSISTENT_STORE_FAILURE when try to initialize with a password. As the error reported from native layer, I couldn't figure out what is the cause.

I also looked at windows event viewer hoping I could find something that could help. But nothing related to this.

How to go about troubleshooting this? Anyone faced this in windows environment?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of the mfp plugin that you are using?

Comment: @Keerthi, 7.1 version. I cannot upgrade to 8.0 :(

Comment: Which windows environment? As per the documentation [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/data/jsonstore/) , only `Hybrid: Android, iOS, Windows Phone 8, and Windows 8` are supported

Comment: The link 'this' in my post shows support to 8 or 8.1. It does work as long as we don't supply password while initializing. Only when encryption gets into the picture, I am getting this error.